# matcher.group(1) return no result

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, matcher

```
    public class GetProp extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String file_proc = readFile();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("Read File contents from SDCARD : \n" + file_proc);
    }
    public String readFile(){
        BufferedReader rdr;
        String proc = "";
        String line;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        try {
            rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/cpuinfo"));     
            while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("Processor: (.*)").matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                proc = matcher.group(1);
            }
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return proc;        
    }
}
```

I want to print one line from /proc/cpuinfo txt file, like Processor: "RESULT", where RESULT is matcher.group(1). But I have no text in th result, where is my problem?

Comment: Well, using `group(1)` would be a start.

Comment: You are probably not finding any matches. Check the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what my `/proc/cpuinfo` looks like:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
/* etc */
```

There are two problems with your regex:

1. Regular expressions are case sensitive. Either change it to `processor`, or use `Pattern.compile(..., Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`.
2. There is whitespace between `processor` and the colon. You should change your regex to     `processor\\s*: (.*)`